# Previous Year's End Value

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap

I'm trying to retrieve the previous year's end value of a measure.

I know this code gets the value of the previous year, but at the same point in time during that year (so Mar 2012 looks to Mar 2011).

```
([Measures].[MeasureName], ParallelPeriod([Time].[Calendar].[Year]))
```

I'd like any date in 2012 to look at the last value in 2011 (Dec 2011). So if we're looking at the Year level of 2012 or any Month level, it all points to Dec 2011.

Answer (score 0):

where are you trying to do this? On a MDX query? Or on a KPI?
Like you can access the value of Dec 2011 like this for example:

```
ParallelPeriod([Time].[Calendar].[Year], 1,  [Time].[Calendar].[Year].[December 2012])
```

Comment: It's an MDX query, so I don't know what the actual member being accessed is (users are browsing the cube)

Answer (score 0):

Combine the time functions:

```
ClosingPeriod([Time].[Calendar].[Month], Ancestor(ParallelPeriod([Time].[Calendar].[Year], 1), [Time].[Calendar].[Year]) )
```